# include specific comments and comment area under a specific category page

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page for a category by slug name to insert posts of the that category .
Now I want to have comments and comment area at the bottom of that page . How to do that ? Can i bring one of that posts comments and comment area in that page via wordpress functions  ? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php wp_list_comments( $args ); ?>
```

Source: Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments